# seperate columns by a delimiter ":" along with column number

Tags: r

I have huge dataframe in the below input format. I am trying to separate the columns based on the delimiter ":" and output the values along with the column number and row value in 1st column.

```
input <- structure(list(V1 = structure(1:2, .Label = c("a1", "a2"), class = "factor"), 
    V2 = structure(1:2, .Label = c("aaa-1-c:bbb-1-d:ccc:a", "www-1-c"
    ), class = "factor"), V3 = structure(1:2, .Label = c("cc:nnn:ttt-cc", 
    "cdd:aaa:pp"), class = "factor"), V4 = structure(c(1L, NA
    ), .Label = "aaa-1-d", class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

I tried but the column numbers and values are not in the proper order.

```
output <- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("a1", "a2 "), class = "factor"), 
    V2 = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), V3 = structure(c(3L, 
    5L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 9L, 11L, 4L, 12L, 8L, 2L, 10L), .Label = c("a", 
    "aaa", "aaa-1-c", "aaa-1-d", "bbb-1-d", "cc", "ccc", "cdd", 
    "nnn", "pp", "ttt-cc", "www-1-c"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-12L))
```

Can anyone please help. Thank you!

Comment: Can you please check the `output` 'V2' column.  Is that  all right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option where we reshape the dataset from 'wide' to 'long' (`pivot_longer` from the `tidyr`  -1.0.0), then split the 'V3' column (in the long format) at the `:` and change the column names in 'V2' to integer with `match`

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
input %>%
   pivot_longer(cols = -V1, names_to = "V2", values_to = "V3", 
          values_drop_na = TRUE) %>% 
   # older versions use gather
   # gather(V2, V3, -V1, na.rm = TRUE) %>%
   separate_rows(V3, sep=":") %>%
   group_by(V1) %>%
   mutate(V2 = match(V2, unique(V2))) %>%
   ungroup
# A tibble: 12 x 3
#   V1       V2 V3     
#   <fct> <int> <chr>  
# 1 a1        1 aaa-1-c
# 2 a1        1 bbb-1-d
# 3 a1        1 ccc    
# 4 a1        1 a      
# 5 a1        2 cc     
# 6 a1        2 nnn    
# 7 a1        2 ttt-cc 
# 8 a1        3 aaa-1-d
# 9 a2        1 www-1-c
#10 a2        2 cdd    
#11 a2        2 aaa    
#12 a2        2 pp
```

Comment: Thank you Akrun! I did load the packages and updated them as well. but it gives me the following error. Error in pivot_longer(., cols = -V1, names_to = "V2", values_to = "V3",  : 
  could not find function "pivot_longer"

Comment: @user11352627  Can you check the `tidyr` version you have?  I used `1.0.0`

Comment: I am using the same version as well .> packageVersion("tidyr")
[1] ‘1.0.0’

Comment: @user11352627  Have you loaded `library(tidyr)`

Comment: @user11352627  I get `packageVersion('tidyr')#
[1] ‘1.0.0’`

Comment: @user11352627  Can you try `input %>%gather(V2, V3, -V1)` (from older version of tidyr.  If this also is not working, some issue in your installation

Comment: Yes I did that, It's the same. > library(tidyr)
> packageVersion('tidyr')  [1] ‘1.0.0’

Comment: This worked input %>%gather(V2, V3, -V1). May be there is some problem with the updated package. I'll look into it. Thank you so much.